# How to construct unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks, event-log

I have custom event logger, and I want to test it.

```
[Test]
        public void AddLogWithExceptionAndEventLogEntryTypeTest()
        {

        const string loggerName = "mockLoggerName";
        var logger = new MyLogger(loggerName);

        System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("System");
        string logValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        logger.AddEntry(new Exception(logValue),EventLogEntryType.Error );


        foreach (
            EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.Message.ToUpper().Contains(logValue))
            {
              //what can is do ?
            }
        }
    }
```

What assert to use to give information, that entry was added ?

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?

Comment: Might be of use http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/260170-nunit-testing-eventlog-entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your intent to look through the log for text you just added? Then how about:

```
bool foundOne = false;
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.Message.ToUpper().Contains(logValue))
        {
          foundOne = true;
        }
    }

Assert(foundOne);
```

Personally, I would instead probably mock the logger, and instead assert that the methods of the mocked logger were called as expected.

Comment: +1: you don't need to test the .NET framework code that writes log messages, just that your class calls those methods with the expected parameters.